# highcharts xAxis min not works in unvenly spaced xAxis data

Tags: highcharts, min, x-axis

in code i provided i have a data series column with unevenly spaced data,
and set min value for xAxis with 1658086242000, but after seeing chart i saw 2 value that is before my min point, why is that?!
my whole code:

```
const simpleData = [ [
                1638748800000,
                1
            ],
            [
                1654387200000,
                2
            ],
            [
                1670284800000,
               3
            ],
            [
                1678060800000,
                4
            ],
            [
                1685923200000,
                5
            ]
        ];
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'Unevenly X axix data min value'
        },

        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            min:1658086242000
        }],
        navigator: {
          enabled: true,
          maskFill: "rgba(37, 150, 190,0.3)",
          series: [{
                type: 'column',
            name: 'series1',
            data: simpleData,
                dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
                }
            }
                    ],
          xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: 'transparent',
          }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'series1',
            data: simpleData,
                        showInNavigator: false,
            dataGrouping: {
               enabled: false,
            }
        }]
    });
```

[sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/kingofday/pumdjk8a/12/)
i already tried startOnTick or pointPlacement but didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the `series.pointRange` which is counted from the distance between the two closest data points and because of that takes more space. You can fix that by changing the `pointRange` and disable `xAxis.ordinal` option.

```
  xAxis: {
      ordinal: false,
      tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // optionally
      ...
    },

  series: [{
    pointRange: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    ...
  }]
```

**Example demos:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8913ge2f/
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tu7vy80z/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.pointRange
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: still can see 2 value column that is before min point

Comment: Hi, this is related to the `series.pointRange` which is counted from the distance between the two closest data points and because of that takes more space (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.pointRange) . You can fix that by changing the pointRange. To illustrate how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n5gvya1m/ and example solution https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n2xeaby9/

Comment: thk, it worked, i wonder why it should not happens by default, can you change answer maybe help some one else